# Span wont work properly

Tags: css, html

I have a Top Navigation where I want a part of the navigation to be on the left side and another part to be on the right side. I've been sitting a while now and don't get it. I don't see why it won't work here is my code:

```
<div id="overhead">
    <div id="overheadText">

    <!-- Home -->
    <a href="index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/List/diverse/home_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/home.png" alt="Home" name="Home" width="65" height="30"   border="0" id="Home" /></a>    
    <!-- Request Streams -->
    <a href="RequestStream.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('RequestStream','','Images/List/diverse/requestStream_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/requestStream.png" alt=    "RequestStream" name="RequestStream" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="RequestStream" /></a>
    <!-- About&Contact -->
    <a href="AboutContact.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('AboutContact','','Images/List/diverse/AboutContact_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/AboutContact.png" alt="About&amp;Contact" name="AboutContact" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="AboutContact" /></a>
    <!-- Play LoL -->
    <a href="http://www.leagueoflegends.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Lol','','Images/List/diverse/Lol_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/Lol.png" alt="Play LeagueofLegends" name="Lol" width="160" height="30" border="0" id="Lol" /></a>

    <!-- All links following should be rightsided (But wont work) -->

    <span style="text-align:right">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('FB','','Images/List/diverse/fb_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/fb.png" alt="Facebook" name="FB" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="FB" /></a>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','Images/List/diverse/tw_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/tw.png" alt="Twitter" name="Twitter" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="Twitter" /></a>
    </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: `<span>` is an inline element. Positioning should be done using a block element like `<p>` or an inline-block element. The span is only as wide as its content, so it can't "text-align" because there's no excess room on either edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't work because your span is an `inline` html component. So it takes the width of its children.

You can use `float: right;` style. It should works better.

Comment: ohh wow how could i forget about float xD Thanx for you help!

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue

```
<div id="overhead">
    <div id="overheadText">
    <div style="float:left">
    <!-- Home -->
    <a href="index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/List/diverse/home_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/home.png" alt="Home" name="Home" width="65" height="30"   border="0" id="Home" /></a>    
    <!-- Request Streams -->
    <a href="RequestStream.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('RequestStream','','Images/List/diverse/requestStream_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/requestStream.png" alt=    "RequestStream" name="RequestStream" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="RequestStream" /></a>
    <!-- About&Contact -->
    <a href="AboutContact.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('AboutContact','','Images/List/diverse/AboutContact_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/AboutContact.png" alt="About&amp;Contact" name="AboutContact" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="AboutContact" /></a>
    <!-- Play LoL -->
    <a href="http://www.leagueoflegends.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Lol','','Images/List/diverse/Lol_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/Lol.png" alt="Play LeagueofLegends" name="Lol" width="160" height="30" border="0" id="Lol" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- All links following should be rightsided (But wont work) -->

    <div style="float:right">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('FB','','Images/List/diverse/fb_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/fb.png" alt="Facebook" name="FB" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="FB" /></a>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','Images/List/diverse/tw_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/tw.png" alt="Twitter" name="Twitter" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="Twitter" /></a>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting them in DIV's and float them on the left/right sides:

```
<div style="float:left;"> <!-- Left part -->

    <!-- Home -->
    <a href="index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/List/diverse/home_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/home.png" alt="Home" name="Home" width="65" height="30"   border="0" id="Home" /></a>    
    <!-- Request Streams -->
    <a href="RequestStream.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('RequestStream','','Images/List/diverse/requestStream_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/requestStream.png" alt=    "RequestStream" name="RequestStream" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="RequestStream" /></a>
    <!-- About&Contact -->
    <a href="AboutContact.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('AboutContact','','Images/List/diverse/AboutContact_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/AboutContact.png" alt="About&amp;Contact" name="AboutContact" width="113" height="30" border="0" id="AboutContact" /></a>
    <!-- Play LoL -->
    <a href="http://www.leagueoflegends.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Lol','','Images/List/diverse/Lol_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/Lol.png" alt="Play LeagueofLegends" name="Lol" width="160" height="30" border="0" id="Lol" /></a>

</div>
    <!-- All links following should be rightsided (But wont work) -->

<div style="float:right;"> <!-- Right part -->

    <span style="text-align:right;">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('FB','','Images/List/diverse/fb_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/fb.png" alt="Facebook" name="FB" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="FB" /></a>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Twitter','','Images/List/diverse/tw_mo.png',1)"><img src="Images/List/diverse/tw.png" alt="Twitter" name="Twitter" width="31" height="30" border="0" id="Twitter" /></a>
    </span>

</div>
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp